# WCF Service hosted in IIS not giving response with HTTPS

Tags: wcf, iis, https, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have developed a sample WCF service and hosted in IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 R2. Note that this server is added to F5 load balancing setup (I do not know the details of this setup) and I am supposed to invoke this service using the URL https://loadbalanceddomainname/servicename.svc.

In the IIS, I have made the below configurations:

1. Created a new website

   2. Created a Self Signed certificate with the subject name "loadbalanceddomainname" and imported to the Personal store.
   3. Bind this certificate to this website on port 443, and host header is set to "loadbalanceddomainname".

With this configuration, when I try to browse the URL https://loadbalanceddomainname/servicename.svc, it gives me a 504 Error (as shown in Fiddler -> "

> [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete
>   response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

")

However, in IIS, if I add one more binding to Port 80 with host header "loadbalanceddomainname", I get the response as shown in the screenshot below.

Though I am able to invoke this service using Https (as shown in address bar) in the browser with the port 80 binding added to IIS, I see that it is getting changed to http as shown in the screenshot below where it says "svcutil.exe http://loadbalanceddomainname/servicename.svc". Why is this https getting changed to http? Why is my service giving 504 error when I remove the Binding at Port 80?

Though I get a response in the browser (with port 80 binding in server), when I try to invoke an operation using a test client (by adding a service reference in Visual Studio and creating a proxy), I get error 404 - no such endpoint exists. The WCF trace log shows the below error as well:

> Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the
>   endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.

[image: Screenshot of the service]

I also have noticed that the certificate I have Bind in IIS is not what I see i the browser, in the above screenshot - when I view the certificate details. Is this a different certificate coming from F5 or somewhere in between?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with this metadata issue. when client tries to access the service over https, it still gets redirected to http because of soap: address location.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2014/10/03/ssl-offloading-in-load-balancer-scenario/

Comment: Why would this be a problem? Does it not work or serve request and response?